# How to use getview() with a SimpleAdapter in Android?

Tags: android, listview, view, simpleadapter

I am generating a `ListView` using a `SimpleAdapter`. My `SimpleAdapter` code is as follows:

```
ListAdapter k = new SimpleAdapter(this, val1, R.layout.mytask, new String[]{"TaskId", "heading", "status"}, new int[]{R.id.View1, R.id.View2, R.id.ViewStatus});
```

My activity is `MainActivity` which `extends Activity`.
I want to `override` the `getview()` method. How can I do that?

Comment: Take one class which extends Simplaeadapter and override getView() method

Comment: I want to keep it as an Activity itself. so any other suggestions?

Comment: It will remain in your activity, you'll just use your own.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it this way:

```
ListAdapter k = new SimpleAdapter(...) {
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ...
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  public class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter{
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data,
                int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        }
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


          // You can customize here.

        }

    }
```

Instead of calling `new SimpleAdapter` you can call something like this

```
 Adapter mAdapter = new Adapter(params);
```

Keep this class as a subclass in your activity itself,

Answer (score 0):

Create class which extends SimpleAdapter and override it's methods. don't forget to handle the constructor and call super(...)

Comment: Is it not possible without extending SimpleAdapter as I want to keep it as an Activity itself

Comment: It will still be in your activity, just instead of SimpleAdapter mAdapter, it will be CustomSimpleAdapter mAdapter :)