# How to change the color of ListView items which is selected form a database

Tags: java, android, listview

In this code the `ListView` is working. However, I need to know how to change the color of the text which is appearing in the list.

This is my code.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>allist=new  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
String[] s1=ou.split("@");

for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++) {
  String []s2=s1[i].split("#");
  HashMap<String,String>hmap=new HashMap<String,String>();

  hmap.put("a", s2[0]);
  hmap.put("b", s2[1]);
  hmap.put("c",s2[2]);
  hmap.put("d", s2[3]);
  hmap.put("e",s2[4]);
  hmap.put("f",s2[5]);
  hmap.put("g",s2[6]);
  allist.add(hmap);
}

ListAdapter lis=new SimpleAdapter(
  getApplicationContext(),
  allist,
  R.layout.calendar_layout,
  new String[] {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"},
  new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6, R.id.textView7}
);
lv.setAdapter(lis);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the getView() as shown in Ziems answer ([How to use getview() with a SimpleAdapter in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904495/how-to-use-getview-with-a-simpleadapter-in-android)). In the getView get a reference to the Textviews you want to modify and set their textcolor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `CustomAdapter` which extends `SimpleAdapter` to get the items in your `ListView` customized. I can suggest implementing your `CustomAdapter` like this.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView yourTextViewForEachItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        // Now set the color of your textview
        yourTextViewForEachItem.setColor(Color.RED);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count=arrayList.size(); //counts the total number of elements from the arrayList.
        return count; //returns the total count to adapter
    }
}
```

You need to initialize your `CustomAdapter` first with the items that you have. Then just set the adapter into your `ListView` and modify your `TextView` based on their position.